# Selling token to any third party tools

Tags: ink, smart-contract

When user stake his NFT, then he earns certain amount of `$EGGS` token which is in-game currency. He can to sell those token to third party tools. How to implement selling token to any third party tools using ink! smart contract?

Comment: Can you elaborate more about the functionality you want to achieve?

Comment: how to sell in-game currency `$EGGS` token earn by user to third party site like `uniswap` using ink! smart contract? I don't know what I am thinking is correct or not.